# Javascript store button element in variable when onclick

Tags: javascript

I have a table with users and want the action buttons to work on the `<tr>` they are children of. When one of the buttons calls a javascript function, I want the function to store the `<tr>` element in a variable so I can work with just the one that holds the button and not affect any other `<tr>` elements. ps: I can use jQuery!

My code:

```js
function editUser() {
  /*
  var button = *the button clicked*;
  var tr = button.getParent(get the <tr> in some way);
  editSomething(tr);
  */
}
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

tr:nth-child(even) td {
  border: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
}

#search {
  padding-bottom: 5vw;
}

.actionLink {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 2px;
}

.actionLink:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>Rank</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Gamanware</td>
      <td>Owner</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Online</td>
      <td>
        <a onclick="editUser()" class="actionLink">Quick Edit</a>
        <a onclick="editUser()" class="actionLink">View</a>
        <a onclick="editUser()" class="actionLink">Delete</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Are you using straight Javascript or do you have JQuery installed? This could change the answer you receive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [closest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) :

```
function editUser(e) {
    let tr = e.closest('tr'); 
}

<tr>
  <td>
    <a onclick="editUser(this)" class="actionLink">Quick Edit</a>
    <a onclick="editUser(this)" class="actionLink">View</a>
    <a onclick="editUser(this)" class="actionLink">Delete</a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Alas not supported cross browser

Comment: @mplungjan true ! not gonna work on IE according to MDN

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`element.parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode) like `.parentNode.parentNode` from current element `a`:

```js
function editUser(thatTR) {
  var tr = thatTR.parentNode.parentNode
  editSomething(tr);
  
}
function editSomething(tr){
  console.log(tr)
}
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

tr:nth-child(even) td {
  border: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
}

#search {
  padding-bottom: 5vw;
}

.actionLink {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 2px;
}

.actionLink:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>Rank</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Gamanware</td>
      <td>Owner</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Online</td>
      <td>
        <a onclick="editUser(this)" class="actionLink">Quick Edit</a>
        <a onclick="editUser(this)" class="actionLink">View</a>
        <a onclick="editUser(this)" class="actionLink">Delete</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**OR:** You can use [`.closest('tr')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest):

```js
function editUser(thatTR) {
  var tr = thatTR.closest('tr');
  editSomething(tr);
}
function editSomething(tr){
  console.log(tr);
}
```

```css
    table {
      font-family: arial, sans-serif;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 100%;
    }

    td,
    th {
      border: 1px solid #dddddd;
      text-align: left;
      padding: 8px;
    }

    tr:nth-child(even) {
      background-color: #dddddd;
    }

    tr:nth-child(even) td {
      border: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
    }

    #search {
      padding-bottom: 5vw;
    }

    .actionLink {
      border: 1px solid black;
      padding: 2px;
    }

    .actionLink:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
    }
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>Rank</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Gamanware</td>
      <td>Owner</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Online</td>
      <td>
        <a onclick="editUser(this)" class="actionLink">Quick Edit</a>
        <a onclick="editUser(this)" class="actionLink">View</a>
        <a onclick="editUser(this)" class="actionLink">Delete</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This only gonna work for the this structure : tr -> td -> the clicked element

Comment: @ElAoutarHamza which it is

Comment: @ElAoutarHamza, do you see any other structure in OP's code?

Comment: What I meant, is that the solution isn't generic. For example if OP want to group all the `a` tags inside a `div` or even use that event handler for `td`, then I don't see how this will work

Answer (score 1):

Have a try with this. It is unobtrusive - i.e. no inline script used

**jQuery** (since you said you could use it):

```js
$(".actionLink").on("click",function() {
    alert($(this).text() + "("+$(this).closest("tr")+")"); 
})
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

tr:nth-child(even) td {
  border: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
}

#search {
  padding-bottom: 5vw;
}

.actionLink {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 2px;
}

.actionLink:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>Rank</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Gamanware</td>
      <td>Owner</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Online</td>
      <td>
        <a class="actionLink">Quick Edit</a>
        <a class="actionLink">View</a>
        <a class="actionLink">Delete</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Plain JS** (with an IE compatible closest):

```js
// element.closest() is not supported by IE at all
var getClosestTr = function(elem) { for ( ; elem && elem !== document; elem = elem.parentNode ) { if (elem.tagName=="TR") return elem;} return null; };

document.querySelectorAll(".actionLink").forEach(function(link) {
  link.onclick=function() {
    alert(this.innerText + "("+getClosestTr(this)+")"); // or this.closest("tr") where supported
  }
})
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

tr:nth-child(even) td {
  border: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
}

#search {
  padding-bottom: 5vw;
}

.actionLink {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 2px;
}

.actionLink:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>Rank</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Gamanware</td>
      <td>Owner</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Online</td>
      <td>
        <a class="actionLink">Quick Edit</a>
        <a class="actionLink">View</a>
        <a class="actionLink">Delete</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: doesn't work for some reason, neither the jQuery or plain js

Comment: It works here with your html. If your html is not the same as here, then perhaps not? I pass the TR object to the function - in jQuery it is a jQuery object

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add an EventListener for clicks to all elements with the `actionLink` class, and then get the TR with `element.parentElement.parentElement` since it's the parent of the parent of the link:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".actionLink").forEach(e => e.addEventListener("click", editUser));

function editUser(e) {
  let tr = (e.target.parentElement.parentElement);
  // doSomethingWith(tr);
}
```

Or, complete:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".actionLink").forEach(e => e.addEventListener("click", editUser));

function editUser(e) {
  let tr = (e.target.parentElement.parentElement);
  // doSomethingWith(tr);
}
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

tr:nth-child(even) td {
  border: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
}

#search {
  padding-bottom: 5vw;
}

.actionLink {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 2px;
}

.actionLink:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>Rank</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Gamanware</td>
      <td>Owner</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Online</td>
      <td>
        <a class="actionLink">Quick Edit</a>
        <a class="actionLink">View</a>
        <a class="actionLink">Delete</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if getting parent `tr` is only thing that you really need, you can access it using `parentElement` of event target. Take a look at modified snippet:

```js
function editUser(button) {
  const tr = button.parentElement.parentElement
  console.log(tr)

}
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

tr:nth-child(even) td {
  border: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
}

#search {
  padding-bottom: 5vw;
}

.actionLink {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 2px;
}

.actionLink:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>Rank</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Gamanware</td>
      <td>Owner</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Online</td>
      <td>
        <a onclick="editUser(this)" class="actionLink">Quick Edit</a>
        <a onclick="editUser(this)" class="actionLink">View</a>
        <a onclick="editUser(this)" class="actionLink">Delete</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: If you pass the anchor, why pass the event? The target IS the anchor

Comment: @mplungjan Indeed... But it may happen, that you need to do something with event. In this particular example it may be overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Set an `id` for each `<tr>` and pass it in the function `editUser(id)`.

Then inside the function just check which is the caller `tr` and only change it using the id for the selector.

Comment: That is not very generic